# Sort the list of employees by day of the week starting Monday in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, sql-order-by

I am writing general sql queries using the default scott schema in oracle.
Using the emp table.

Here I want to display and sort the results on the basis of day which should start from Monday. i.e those hired on Monday should come at the top , then for tuesday and so on till sunday.

I wrote this query as :

```
select * from emp order by to_char(hiredate,'DAY') ;
```

But the above query is displaying results in alphabetical order of the week days i.e ( People hired on Friday coming at the top , then Monday , Saturday and so on)

Kinldy help.

Comment: Maybe `select * from emp order by to_char(hiredate,'D') ;`

Comment: @DavidAldridge - that may work in the UK, but it will not work in the US. The `'D'` option depends on local settings (`nls_region` and such), which cannot be given as an input to `TO_CHAR` - and in America, Sunday = 1, Monday = 2.

Comment: @mathguy Ah yes of course!

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
select * from emp order by trunc(hire_date) - trunc(hire_date, 'IW')
```

This works by computing the number of days elapsed since the beginning of the week (starting Monday). It will return `0` for Monday and `6` for Sunday.

---

**Why this works**

```
trunc(hire_date) - trunc(hire_date, 'IW')
```

It's all in the documentation of [Oracle date format specifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) :

> `IW` : Calendar week of year (1-52 or 1-53), as defined by the ISO 8601 standard. *A calendar week starts on Monday*.

As this specifier relies on ISO standard, it is not affected by the NLS settings of the session in which it is called (see further about the complications this avoids). This makes this approach full portable (and still quite efficient, as it consists in just two conversions).

---

**The problem with the `TO_CHAR` approach**

Oracle provides the [`TO_CHAR()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions188.htm#SQLRF06129) which can be used with the `D` format specifier to return the day of the week. As documented, *this element depends on the NLS territory of the session*.

The [`NLS_TERRITORY` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams156.htm#REFRN10128) says :

> `NLS_TERRITORY` specifies the name of the territory whose conventions are to be followed for day and week numbering.

By default, this session parameter is initialized from server's default. So to use the `D` specifier in a portable way, you would need to first alter your session settings.

But beware that this parameter also controls the *default* of other session parameters (date format, decimal separator, currency symbol, ...) : modifying it could affect other queries running in the same session in suprising ways.

**Consider this demonstration**

Today is Wednesday, January 28, hence the third day of the week. We are creating a new session without specifying any NLS parameter, and then :

```
SELECT parameter, value from v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TERRITORY';

PARAMETER     | VALUE  
:------------ | :------
NLS_TERRITORY | AMERICA
```

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd') FROM DUAL;

 | TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D') |
 | :------------------- |
 | 4                    |
```

When using server's default territory (America), we are getting the wrong result : Oracle considers that, in America,  weeks start on Sunday.

Let's alter the parameter to a territory where weeks start on Monday :

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'FRANCE';
```

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd') FROM DUAL;

 | TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D') |
 | :------------------- |
 | 3                    |
```

Now we are getting the result we wanted... However, you should aware that, in the meantime, Oracle changed session parameter `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` from `.,` to `,` : this happened because the default value of `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` was implicitely changed (when `NLS_TERRITORY` was changed) AND no value had been explicitely for this parameter set by the client. Tricky.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=345a2b63e4e906d633289dbcf7df9ab5)**

NB : unlike `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` parameter, Oracle does not allow to pass `NLS_TERRITORY` as a third argument to `TO_CHAR`(I imagine that it's because it controls the defaults of other parameters).